# Error connecting SQL server to MVC3 application - A network-related or instance-specific error 

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2008

I'm getting this error since I've moved my mvc3/entity framework site onto the live server from localhost.  Normally when I would get this error, I'd check the database name, password and server are all correct in the connection string.  I have checked this - they all seem fine.

I have aspnet Membership provider on the site within the database, and it allows me to login, verifies me, then tries to redirect me to another page, and then that's where the error happens - i.e., as soon as I connect to the database outwith the membership provider.

The database is on the same server as the site, and when I connect from localhost to the remote server, it works perfectly.

Here is the full error message:

```
Exception message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Here is the connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.43;Initial Catalog=BlueLadder;User Id=BlueLadderAdmin;Password=Auth1991;timeout=30" />
```

Anyone anything I could try?

Comment: Just a thought - I notice your Data Source is an internal IP address - is your live server on the same subnet as your development machine?  I would log into your server and try to ping 192.168.1.43 just to be sure.  If that works, do a port check to ensure 1433 is open between your live server and your database.

Comment: Hi Justin - Yes, I'm able to ping it, and port 1433 is open.

Comment: Ok one thing I'm not sure about is that when I check the server roles for my user in SQL server, it has check boxes for all the aspnet membership provider items, such as aspnet_WebEvent_FullAccess.  Could this have any effect?  I'm really running out of ideas here..

Comment: Does anyone else have a system that has their website data and membership data in the same database?  Does it work remotely without a hitch?  I've seen a few posts that seem to think you need a separate database for membership, but that seems really unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, despite my connection string in the web config, it was actually being ignored and the application was still trying to connect to a local version.  Apparently you need to pass the connection string through the dbContext constructor, like so.

```
public Context()
            : base("ConnectionString")
        {
        }
```

[Question was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011660/code-first-entity-framework-change-connection-string/7011739#7011739)

Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Data Source and Initial Catalog, and replace them with something like this:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BlueLadder;
```

I don't know if you're using SQLEXPRESS, so just modify accordingly if you're not.

Comment: No, that hasn't worked - I wondered that myself and tried it earlier but made no difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your server is accepting remote connections and has TCP/IP provider enabled. You can configure this using "Sql Server Configuration Manager" on your server
2. You could try specifying the named instance of your server. "Sql Server Configuration Manager" can tell you what instances are installed on your server.

Server = 192.168.1.43/MSSQLSERVER or 
Server = 192.168.1.43/SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vasile.  The server is accepting remote connections and TCPIP is enabled.  Other applications are working fine on this server as well - seems to be just mine that is throwing an error.

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I'm convinced it has something to do with the aspnet Membership provider.  As I said, it allows me to login, but it's not reading the roles section properly, because I should be admin, and therefore have access to more menus. I'll keep looking into it...

Comment: Maybe this will help you from MSDN regarding membership schema "The database elements that are installed in the application services database will always be owned by the SQL Server database owner account (dbo). You do not need to be a system administrator for the computer running SQL Server to install the application services database. To install the application services database, a SQL Server login must be permitted to the db_ddladmin and dd_securityadmin roles for the SQL Server database." You account must be db_owner to use membership.

Comment: Ok, I've updated a setting in the RoleManager in the web.config (there was an erroneous string in the Application field) , so the roles are now working. Getting there...

Comment: Hmm - my login was already an owner and I've added the other two permissions but without progress. :(

Comment: The connection strings for Membership, Profile and RoleManager all use the same ApplicationServices connection string, so you would think it would either all work or none of it would work