# asp mvc 3 noobie: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm an asp mvc 3 noobie. I've done a few [tutorials](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx) and am now ready to keep learning by trying to build a site.

In all the tutorials, you connect to a SQL CE or SQL Express DB. But I want my site to build a DB on sql server.

I created a database on my networked server that I'll call MyDB. Then I set my connection string in my web config file like this:

```
add name="ApplicationServices"
    connectionString="Data Source=Server\ServerInstance;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I created models and a scaffolding controller.

I created a simple DataBaseContext like this:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class DatabaseContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Employee As DbSet(Of Employee)
    Public Property AnnualLeave As DbSet(Of AnnualLeave)

End Class
```

But when I hit the following line in the scaffolding controller, i get the error:

```
 Function Index() As ViewResult
    Return View(db.Employee.ToList()) //CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'`.
 End Function
```

1. Should I fix this by changing the permissions on the MyDB database? Is this a permissions issue on the SQL server side? I am confused why I am getting a Create database error because the DB already exists.
2. Am I getting this error b/c I have already created the database? Does the scaffolding want to create the database somehow?

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to create a new DB by the error message.  I'm guessing that you are using EF code first with your project and using it's migration capability to build your DB.  Check the setup of the EF context to make sure it's using your connection string.

Comment: @swannee thanks for your help. Where do I check the setup of the EF context to make sure it's using your connection string?

Comment: Try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011660/code-first-entity-framework-change-connection-string

Comment: @swannee thanks again. following that post, I changed the name of my connection string to match the name of the datacontext. That brought me a new error message...progress! If you want to write up an answer with the jist of this (make sure the name of connection string matches the datacontext) i will accept.

Comment: Cool hope that helped! I added an answer reflecting this conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it is trying to create a new DB by the error message. I'm guessing that you are using EF code first with your project and using it's migration capability to build your DB. Check the setup of the EF context to make sure it's using your connection string.

The connection string or its name can be passed to constructor of DbContext. If you are using default constructor it searches for the connection string with the same name as the name of your derived context class.  Basically, make sure your connection string has the same name as your derived dbcontext class and it should find it.

[See this post for additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011660/code-first-entity-framework-change-connection-string)

Comment: any idea on this one? this was my next error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940809/asp-mvc-3-noobie-why-am-i-getting-a-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-0x80131

Answer (score 3):

1.You need to set IIS app pool identity to be ASP.NET integration mode.

2.Add a login in SQL Server for IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET.

3.In SQL Server, set IIS APP POOL login to have dbcreator role.

Comment: I DONT want it to create a DB. I created the models from an existing database and published to server its giving me this error. I am not even using any initialsers

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. But you should be accurate in the answer. The login you need to add is IIS APPPOOL\{apppool name of your site}

Answer (score 0):

USE master;
EXECUTE sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'YourAppUserLogin', @rolename = N'dbcreator';

Answer (score 0):

```html
<add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test2;user id=sa;password=123456" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Use this connection string for your application